# Returning properties of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to build a deck of cards and remove one of them, returning their individual name, suit and values properties as separate elements.  I have created a card object, each with a "name", "suit" and "value", and placed 52 of them in a "Deck" array.  I want to draw a single "Card" from the deck array and use their individual properties for a card game, but am not sure how to do this properly.  Below is an example of the way I am trying to make this happen.

```
//CARD OBJECT
function card(name, suit, value) {
    this.name = name;
    this.suit = suit;
    this.value = value;
}

//NEW DECK ARRAY
var cardsInDeck = new Array();

//INDIVIDUAL CARD OBJECTS IN THE DECK ARRAY
var aceSpades = new card("Ace", "Spades", 1);
cardsInDeck.push(aceSpades);
var twoSpades = new card("Two", "Spades", 2);
cardsInDeck.push(twoSpades);
var threeSpades = new card("Three", "Spades", 3);
cardsInDeck.push(threeSpades);
var fourSpades = new card("Four", "Spades", 4);
cardsInDeck.push(fourSpades);
var fiveSpades = new card("Five", "Spades", 5);
//REPEATED FOR ALL 52 CARDS

//SHUFFLE CARDS
var shuffle = function() {

var theLength = cardsInDeck.length - 1;
var toSwap;
var tempCard;

for (var i = theLength; i > 0; i--) {
    toSwap = Math.floor(Math.random() * i);
    tempCard = cardsInDeck[i];
    cardsInDeck[i] = cardsInDeck[toSwap];
    cardsInDeck[toSwap] = tempCard;
    }
}

shuffle();

//DRAW ONE CARD
var drawOne = function() {
var card = cardsInDeck.slice(cardsInDeck.length - 1);
cardsInDeck.length--;
return card;
}

console.log(drawOne());
```

I can get one "Card" to be drawn, but it returns an Array(1) which has the name, suit and value of each card...but I'm not sure how to get those properties separated and use them to build the game.  I am sure this is quite simple and that I am overlooking something small, but I am quite new to programming and have not found a solution that specifically applies to this problem.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: this is worded kind of confusingly, but maybe what you're looking for is the array map operator?

Side comment: I hope you didn't actually build 52 relatively sequential objects by hand instead of writing some loops...

Comment: Do you just want to `return card[0]` from the function? [`slice` returns an array so you need grab the first element if you want the card object](https://jsfiddle.net/21y1crqe/).

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, want to draw a random "Card" from the "Deck" and use the values of those cards to create a Baccarat game.  I am just stuck on how I can get just the "Value" of each card and assign it to a variable.

Comment: If you use Mr. Geeks answer [you get the value with `let value = drawOne().value`](https://jsfiddle.net/21y1crqe/1/).

Comment: Thank you Andy, the combination of Mr. Geeks answer and your comment did what I was trying to accomplish!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `var card = cardsInDeck.pop();` to draw the card. And you can't use `cardsInDeck.length--;`, instead, pop will remove the last card and so the length will be automatically decremented, and for less and better code, just use return without creating a variable, so your function should be :

```
var drawOne = function() {
   return cardsInDeck.pop();
}
```

And, instead of creating all the cards manually, use this for less and better code :

```
var cardsInDeck = [];
var suits = ["Spades","Hearts","Clubs","Diamonds"];
var names = ["One","Two","Three","Four","Five","Six","Seven","Eight","Nine","Ten","Jack","Queen","King"];
var values = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13];
var card;

for (var i=0; i<suits.length; i++) {
    for (var j=0; j<names.length; j++) {
        cardsInDeck.push(new card(names[j], suits[i], values[j]));
    }
}
```

And to get the value, name or suit of the drawn card, use :

```
var card = drawOne();
var cardValue = card.value;
var cardName = card.name;
var cardSuit = card.suit;
```

Comment: Now, how would you recommend I retrieve the value of this card that has been pulled from the deck using the "drawOne" function?  I want to assign the "value" of each pulled "card" to a variable so I can use it in a Baccarat card game?

Answer (score 0):

If I got you correctly you might search for something like this one here:

```
//CARD OBJECT
function card(name, suit, value) {
  this.name = name
  this.suit = suit
  this.value = value
}

//NEW DECK ARRAY
var cardsInDeck = new Array()

//INDIVIDUAL CARD OBJECTS IN THE DECK ARRAY
var aceSpades = new card('Ace', 'Spades', 1)
cardsInDeck.push(aceSpades)
var twoSpades = new card('Two', 'Spades', 2)
cardsInDeck.push(twoSpades)
var threeSpades = new card('Three', 'Spades', 3)
cardsInDeck.push(threeSpades)
var fourSpades = new card('Four', 'Spades', 4)
cardsInDeck.push(fourSpades)
var fiveSpades = new card('Five', 'Spades', 5)
cardsInDeck.push(fiveSpades)
//REPEATED FOR ALL 52 CARDS

//DRAW ONE CARD
var drawOne = function() {
  if(cardsInDeck.length > 0){
    return cardsInDeck.splice(Math.random() * (cardsInDeck.length-1),1)[0]  
  }
}

// EXAMPLE EXECUTION
console.log(drawOne())
console.log(drawOne())
console.log(drawOne())
console.log(drawOne())
console.log(drawOne())
console.log(cardsInDeck.length)
```

An example execution would like this:

[image]